# MSM - Template on site 1 and I want different url on site 2 to goto that template

Tags: ee2, templates, multi-site-manager, pages, page-uri

I need help with Multi Site Manager - running on EE2:

All templates are on on Site 1.
So for example one template is
"promotions/index" -> showing as "/promotions" naturally.

On Site 2 I want the url be different e.g. 
/aktionen but use this same template.

How do I link up/map this different name to go to /promotions/index in Site 1?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Per the docs: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/msm/code.html#embedding-templates-from-another-site

Just embed the template and pass the variables.

'{embed="site_short_name:template_group/template"}'

Comment: But where would I put this code? 
I would need to put it inside a new template called aktionen/index.php and embed it to point to the promotions/index.php ??

Comment: Yes. Create the template as normal, (where you want the new page), then use the the format provided to include the template you want used.